# Configure SharePoint Apps on Production environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, 404

We are in the process of installing APPS on our Production SharePoint environment. We have two w.f.e servers which are load balanced. We created two domains with two certificates.

contoso.com and
contosoapps.com

We created two network adapters and assigned a unique ip address to each. One ipaddress points to the domain contoso.com and the other to contosoapps.com. In the server, for SharePoint websites, we included the ip address of contoso.com and inserted wildcard certificate *.contoso.com.

We created a new web application with no host header and binded the ipaddress of constoapps.com to this webapplication and inserted wildcard certificate *.contosoapps.com.

However, when accessing the app, 404 error is thrown.  the requested resource is not found. 
Any help?

[image]

Comment: 404 is a permission issue , accessing the app doesnt have proper permissions . I had similar issue when i created a spprovider app at the line in default.aspx : clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Nikhil, I had previously stopped the default website running on the server. Now, I deleted it, cannot display the page error is thrown.

Comment: What type of app? (This matters, for instance if it is provider hosted you don't need the DNS stuff at all)

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/04/30/intermittent-quot-http-403-forbidden-quot-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app.aspx

This issue usually occurs when a request from an authenticated user without local admin rights results in a failed read of the /BIN directory by the impersonating w3wp.exe (IIS worker process for ASP.NET) process. This behavior is typically associated with lack of permissions to the temporary folder /BIN where ASP.Net assemblies are Just In Time (JIT) compiled.

Comment: I am able to access the SharePoint sites. It is only when I click on an installed app(third party). I recieve page not found errors. Since the apps are stored in a different web application, where I should be looking to fix this issue?